# Trouble with mongoexport -query command

Tags: mongodb, export

I am trying to export a subset of documents that contain a specific ObjectId from a collection of Twitter searches. To do this, I am using the following script:

```
mongoexport --db twitter --collection tweets --csv --fieldFile CSVfields.txt --out .\tweets.csv --query query.txt
```

...where *CSVfields.txt* references the specific document keys that I want in the export and *query.txt* contains:

```
{ "search" : ObjectId("525f9cfdb3685db029000001") }
```

When I run this, I get an error saying:

*assertion: 16619 code FailedToParse: FailedToParse: Expecting '{': offset:0*

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`--query` takes a JSON query, not a file.

So either of the following should work:

```
mongoexport --db twitter --collection tweets --csv --fieldFile CSVfields.txt --out .\tweets.csv --query `cat query.txt`

mongoexport --db twitter --collection tweets --csv --fieldFile CSVfields.txt --out .\tweets.csv --query '{ "search" : ObjectId("525f9cfdb3685db029000001") }'
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel for the response. I had tried the second option but not the first. Both keep giving me this error which I seem to be getting with everything I try: "ERROR: too many positional options"

Comment: I figured it out. My console wasn't escaping the JSON argument. When I nested my quotations starting with " and then ', it did the trick. This syntax worked: mongoexport --db twitter --collection tweets --csv --fieldFile CSVfields.txt --out tweets.csv --query "{ search : ObjectId('52613e36b3685db029000004') }"